# How do you store an image that has been uploaded using node/express?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm using an Angular MEAN stack. ( Node, Express, Angular, Mongo/Mongoose).

I'm trying to figure out how to upload an image using the input type file.

HTML as it stands:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <label class="app-file-input button">
        <span>Upload</span>
        <i class="icon-enter"></i>
        <input type="file"/>
    </label>
</form>
```

I've added the input html but I'm wondering how I would go about storing that image so I can call for it at any point. Would I have to do this in the controller? And then push it to my middleware?

If you are aware of any good tutorials on this subject please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage)

[Azure Blob service to upload, download, list, and delete blob content. Samples are written in Node.js.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/#how-to-download-blobs)